# Does CODEOWNERS support glob pattern in file name

Tags: github-codeowners

I had syntax error for CODEOWNERS file while PR.

I understand glob pattern like * wildcard is supported directory level and ** across different directory but wondering if files like below should be supported. If not do I just have to specify each line or rearrange directory? Those are in the same **roles/** directory.

```
locations/location::Main::a.yaml                             @@"Contributors"
locations/location::Main::b.yaml                             @@"Contributors"
locations/location::Sub::c.yaml                              @@"Contributors"
locations/location::Sub::d.yaml                              @@"Contributors"
```

to set codeowners like these.

```
locations/location::Main::*.yaml                             @@"Contributors"
locations/location::Sub::*.yaml                              @@"Contributors"
```

in the shell it works but understand CODEOWNERS follows the pattern rule used in .gitignore

Comment: Just in case, raised a question in [Code Owners for Bitbucket](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CODEOWNERS/overview?homepageId=222494772) then found out that is not an issue with the glob (still not all globs in shell/bash are supported) but colon `:` in the file name. Team will check to see if colons in file globs can be allowed in a next release.

Comment: Is this question about GitHub or Bitbucket? The tag is specifically GitHub, but the syntax suggests BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does support `**` globs.

The `CODEOWNERS` file [supports most patterns](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners#codeowners-syntax) allowed by [`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#:%7E:text=Two%20consecutive%20asterisks):

> A CODEOWNERS file uses a pattern that follows most of the same rules used in gitignore files.